# Why my article is rejected to published as a guest writer?

Tags: problem, writing

As I'm a new article writer, told me that it's not well-enough with SEO and quality content. But I can't find its proper problem. So, it'll be really nice and appreciable, if anyone can find me actually what's the problem is?

Here is the Google docs link of my article:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wvJ5-8WPx65ah_AV7YVwoBmiMW6JL-pxWsgmix3uUhE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid your English is nowhere near good enough for you to be writing professionally in English. The article (and this question) are full of grammatical errors, poor word choices and syntax that looks very odd to a native speaker.